# Binding an MVVM IEnumerable<POCO> to MyGeneration BLL entities (real-time)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, ienumerable, observablecollection, bindinglist

I am working on my first WPF project using MVVM. I have successfully managed to abstract away my service layer so that I could use (for instance) XML files to store the data. Using IEnumerable collections of my POCO's, any changes to the table on the GUI automaticaly propagated to repository.

Now I'm trying to switch over to using our company DB2 database instead. We use MyGeneration dOOdads to generate DAL's and BLL's for our DB2 database. The DAL's have built-in CRUD and other utility methods.

One of my colleagues has managed to successfully bind the MyGeneration BLL DataView to his WPF application (he did not use MVVM) so that it too could make real-time changes to the DataView (only requiring a call to the BLL's SaveChanges method).

My problem is that in the translation between the MyGeneration DataView, and my collection of POCO's, I would need to explicitly update any changes at this layer.

Am I approaching this the wrong way? Would something like AutoMapper be an answer to my problem, or would I still not have real-time mapping?

```
public override IEnumerable<PromotionPlanHeader> ReadAll()
{
    foreach (DataRow row in bll_PROMPLANH.DefaultView.Table.Rows)
    {
        yield return new PromotionPlanHeader
        {
            PlanNumber = Convert.ToInt32(row["PLANNUMBER"]),
            Active = (row["ACTIVE"].ToString() == "1"),
            Capturer = row["CAPTURER"].ToString(),
            Region = row["REGION"].ToString(),
            Cycle = row["CYCLE"].ToString(),
            Channel = row["CHANNEL"].ToString(),
            StartDate = ConvertDb2Date(row["STARTDATE"].ToString()),
            EndDate = ConvertDb2Date(row["ENDDATE"].ToString()),
            AdvertStartDate = ConvertDb2Date(row["ADVERTSTARTDATE"].ToString()),
            AdvertEndDate = ConvertDb2Date(row["ADVERTENDDATE"].ToString()),
            BpcsDealNumber = Convert.ToInt32(row["BPCSDEALNUMBER"]),
            Description = row["DESCRIPTION"].ToString(),
            DeactivationReason = row["DEACTIVATIONREASON"].ToString(),
            LastSavedUsername = row["LASTUSER"].ToString(),
            LastSavedDateTime = ConvertDb2DateTime(row["LASTDATE"].ToString(), row["LASTDATE"].ToString().PadLeft(6, '0'))
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ["WPF DataGrid Practical Examples"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples) walkthrough has really cleared up some things for me. Particularly, the *Binding in a Layered Application* chapter, which demonstrates how you handle Updates and Inserts with an IEditableObject interface.

Although that makes me wonder if a BindingList is not better(?)